# Make this background transparent, then visable then STAY visable

Tags: html, css

so this is what I'm working with here:

HTML:

```
<div id="smith">
    <img class="top" src="http://i.imgur.com/D6Kohra.png"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#smith {
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/1ABXZ1y.png") no-repeat center;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out 0;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out 0;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out 0;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out 0;
}

#smith img {
  position:fixed;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out 180s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out 180s;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out 180s;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out 180s;
}

#smith img.top {
    position:fixed;
    display:inline;
    left:50%;
}

#smith img.top:hover {
      opacity:0;
      transition:0;
}

#smith img.bottom:hover {
  transition:0;
}
```

Basically; I'm trying to get it to show the top image first, then upon hover, change to seeing the bottom image but also FREEZING the bottom image so that even off hover you continue to see the bottom image.

I have it up in JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mcKempt/gyn8fdt4/

My issue is the background is either visible all the time, or I can hide it but it stays hidden even on hover. Tried making it into it's own separate image first and setting opacity to 0, but it still was visible or non-visible when I didn't want it.

If there is a better way to do this that setting the transition thing to '180s', do tell.

Also more info sites would be the bomb.
I can only use CSS/HTML.

Thanks

Comment: Changing "states" on a permanent basis is functionality better suited to Javascript.

Comment: Sorry, posted before my edit!!; I can only use HTML/CSS for where I'm putting this. :/

Comment: The only states that I can think of in CSS are the pseudoclasses `:visited` etc. on links, `:target` on anything with an id, but requires clicking, and I think there's `:invalid` now for form fields? But none of these suggests itself to your application.

Comment: Alright; is what it is. Any chance maybe an HTML5 thing would do it, or does that involve clicking the image? (or would that even work?)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment above **permanent** changes would require Javascript.

However, a **semi-permanent** effect can be faked using a very long transition-duration on the base state and a short transition on the 'returning' `:hover` state.

```css
#smith {
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 87px;
  width: 383px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 25px;
  background: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/") no-repeat center;
}
#smith img.top {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 999s ease;
}
#smith img.top:hover {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="smith">
  <img class="top" src="http://i.imgur.com/D6Kohra.png" />
</div>
```

For the background-image, these cannot be transitioned. Therefore I suggest a pseudo-element solution.

```css
#smith {
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 87px;
  width: 383px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 25px;
  position: relative;
}
#smith:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/") no-repeat center;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 999s ease;
}
#smith:hover:before {
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
#smith img.top {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 999s ease;
}
#smith img.top:hover {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="smith">
  <img class="top" src="http://i.imgur.com/D6Kohra.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: I can just delay, that's fine. However, is there any way to make the background not-visible until hover?

Comment: You can't transition a background image if that's what you are asking.

Comment: By any chance, would this be better suited for, say, text instead of an image?

Comment: It entirely depend on what you are trying to do.